# How will be better to set up data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I have a data `DataFrame` which I want to transform in a pivot table. How to set the columns label with years and dates as index ? and how do you think will be better to organize this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just set an index:

```
df.set_index(['City', 'RegionName'])
```

Then it will be something like this:

```
                             2014-01
New York   Upper East Side     ...
           Williamsburg        ...
```

Comment: and if want to set the column names with years as a level 1 index for this `DataFrame` how can I do this?

Comment: @Sinchetru: You should post a new question.  :)